# Crash when closing document in cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a document based cocoa app where each document is a web view.

Sometime when I close a document it crashes.  Running Zombies it says `An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated 'MyDocument' object (zombie)` when the crash happens.

It says the responsible caller is `-[NSDocumentController makeUntitledDocumentOfType:error:]`.

I don't understand why this method would be getting called after I close a document.

Comment: Can u post code from your document controller and document class? Also, are you using bindings?

Comment: No on both but I'm only subclassing NSDocument.  I found if I keep a pointer to each document as they are closed there is no crash.

Comment: Shouldn't **Zombies** also give you a hint where the object was deallocated??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution after some help using a technical support incident with Apple.

I had to nil out the ui delegate in my -dealloc.  Everything works fine now.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [self.webView setUIDelegate:nil];
}
```

The engineer told me for compatibility reasons even when using ARC most objects still have to use `__unsafe_unretained` references for their delegates instead of `__weak`.